# Highchart accessing series.data in tooltip pointFormat

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

https://jsfiddle.net/z6rvjem5/

series.data would show an array of objects in the tooltip, but series.data[0] just gives undefined. How do I access the actual data and show in pointformatter (for example: I want to show the difference between every y value and the previous one without setting
 `compare: 'value'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pointFormat` doesn't support more than one nesting level. Use `pointFormatter` function which has more flexibility.

```
    pointFormatter: function(){
        var point = this,
            series = point.series;

        return `${series.name}: <b>${point.y}</b><br/>${series.data[0].y}`
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1ets3xn2/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter